# How to maintain data to be both implemented and documented (in a personal package)

Tags: external-files, parsing, csv

I'm looking for the best strategy for maintaining, in a personal package, a
(long) list of data that has to be defined in the implementation and to be
documented in the documentation.

Let me be more explicit with the following use case: in this personal package,
I define some expressions that have to be translated either in French or in
English. For this, I make use of the `translator` package and, hence, create a
French and an English dictionaries with same keys and corresponding
translations:

French dictionary:

```
\ProvidesDictionary {mypackage}{French}
\deftranslation {abstract}{Résumé}
\deftranslation {draft}{Brouillon}
```

English dictionary:

```
\ProvidesDictionary {mypackage}{English}
\deftranslation {abstract}{Abstract}
\deftranslation {draft}{Draft}
```

I want these translations to appear in the package's documentation, for
instance as a table that shows the correspondence between French and English,
like this:

```
| Label    | FrenchValue | EnglishValue |
|----------+-------------+--------------|
| abstract | Résumé      | Abstract     |
| draft    | Brouillon   | Draft        |
```

I can achieve this in the following way:

```
% \iffalse meta-comment
%<*internal>
\def\nameofplainTeX{plain}
\ifx\fmtname\nameofplainTeX\else
  \expandafter\begingroup
\fi
%</internal>
%<*install>
\input docstrip.tex
\keepsilent
\askforoverwritefalse
\generate{
  \file{\jobname.sty}{\from{\jobname.dtx}{package}}
  \file{French.dict}{\from{\jobname.dtx}{French-dict}}
  \file{English.dict}{\from{\jobname.dtx}{English-dict}}
}
%</install>
%<install>\endbatchfile
%<*internal>
\generate{
  \file{\jobname.ins}{\from{\jobname.dtx}{install}}
}
\ifx\fmtname\nameofplainTeX
  \expandafter\endbatchfile
\else
  \expandafter\endgroup
\fi
%</internal>
%<*package>
\NeedsTeXFormat{LaTeX2e}
\ProvidesPackage{\jobname}
%</package>
%<*driver>
\documentclass{ltxdoc}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{\jobname}
\begin{document}
  \DocInput{\jobname.dtx}
\end{document}
%</driver>
% \fi
%
% \section{Dictionaries}
%
% Translations are summarized in Table~\ref{tab:translations}.
% \begin{table}[hb]
%   \centering
%   \begin{tabular}{lll}
%     Label    & French Value & English Value \\\hline
%     abstract & Résumé       & Abstract      \\
%     draft    & Brouillon    & Draft
%   \end{tabular}
%   \caption{Translations}
%   \label{tab:translations}
% \end{table}
%
%\StopEventually{}
%
% \subsection{French dictionary}
%
%    \begin{macrocode}
%<*French-dict>
%    \end{macrocode}
%
% \begin{description}
% \item[Identification:]
%    \begin{macrocode}
\ProvidesDictionary{\jobname}{French}
%    \end{macrocode}
% \item[Translations:]
%    \begin{macrocode}
\deftranslation{abstract}{Résumé}
\deftranslation{draft}{Brouillon}
%    \end{macrocode}
% \end{description}
%
%    \begin{macrocode}
%</French-dict>
%    \end{macrocode}
%
% \subsection{English dictionary}
%
%    \begin{macrocode}
%<*English-dict>
%    \end{macrocode}
%
% \begin{description}
% \item[Identification:]
%    \begin{macrocode}
\ProvidesDictionary{\jobname}{English}
%    \end{macrocode}
% \item[Translations:]
%    \begin{macrocode}
\deftranslation{abstract}{Abstract}
\deftranslation{draft}{Draft}
%    \end{macrocode}
% \end{description}
%
%    \begin{macrocode}
%</English-dict>
%    \end{macrocode}
%
% \Finale
```

The problem is that is not easy to maintain if the list of translation is long.
Hence I'm looking for a strategy to have a single input of the data (the
translations), for instance as a `.csv` file, and to be able to both:

- define them with the right `translator` syntax,
- document them, for instance as a table.

In the following MCE, I am able to do this with:

1. the `docstrip`'s `\generate` macro that lets me create a `.csv` file containing
   the data,
2. the `\newwrite`, `\immediate`, `\openout`, `\write` TeX macros that let me write in the external French and English dictionaries files,
3. the `csvtools` package that lets me loop the `.csv` file to:

   - populate the external French and English dictionaries files,
   - create in one go a table displaying the content of the `.csv` file,

but I wonder if it is the best way of doing.

```
% \iffalse meta-comment
%<*internal>
\def\nameofplainTeX{plain}
\ifx\fmtname\nameofplainTeX\else
  \expandafter\begingroup
\fi
%</internal>
%<*install>
\input docstrip.tex
\keepsilent
\askforoverwritefalse
\generate{
  \file{\jobname.sty}{\from{\jobname.dtx}{package}}
  \nopreamble\nopostamble
  \file{translations.csv}{\from{\jobname.dtx}{translations}}
}
%</install>
%<install>\endbatchfile
%<*internal>
\generate{
  \file{\jobname.ins}{\from{\jobname.dtx}{install}}
}
\ifx\fmtname\nameofplainTeX
  \expandafter\endbatchfile
\else
  \expandafter\endgroup
\fi
%</internal>
%<*package>
\NeedsTeXFormat{LaTeX2e}
\ProvidesPackage{\jobname}
%</package>
%<*driver>
\documentclass{ltxdoc}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{\jobname}
\begin{document}
  \DocInput{\jobname.dtx}
\end{document}
%</driver>
% \fi
%
% Translations are summarized in Table~\ref{tab:translations}.
% \begin{table}[hb]
%   \centering
%   \CSVtotabular{expressions.csv}{lll}{^^A
%     Label & FrenchValue & EnglishValue\\\hline^^A
%   }{^^A
%     \insertLabel &
%     \insertFrenchValue &
%     \insertEnglishValue\\^^A
%   }{^^A
%     \insertLabel &
%     \insertFrenchValue &
%     \insertEnglishValue^^A
%   }
%   \caption{Translations}
%   \label{tab:translations}
% \end{table}
%
%\StopEventually{}
%
%    \begin{macrocode}
%<*translations>
%    \end{macrocode}
%
% Store the translations in an external, .csv, file.
%    \begin{macrocode}
Label,FrenchValue,EnglishValue
abstract,Résumé,Abstract
draft,Brouillon,Draft
%    \end{macrocode}
%
%    \begin{macrocode}
%</translations>
%    \end{macrocode}
%
%    \begin{macrocode}
%<*package>
%    \end{macrocode}
%
% Load the csvtools package.
%    \begin{macrocode}
\RequirePackage{csvtools}
%    \end{macrocode}
%
% Prepare to write to external dictionary files.
%    \begin{macrocode}
\newwrite\frenchdict
\immediate\openout\frenchdict=French.dict
\newwrite\englishdict
\immediate\openout\englishdict=English.dict
%    \end{macrocode}
%
% Identify the dictionaries in their corresponding files.
%    \begin{macrocode}
\immediate\write\frenchdict{%
  \unexpanded{\ProvidesDictionary}{\jobname}{French}%
}%
\immediate\write\englishdict{%
  \unexpanded{\ProvidesDictionary}{\jobname}{English}%
}%
%    \end{macrocode}
%
% Use the translations.csv file to populate the dictionaries files (thanks to
% csvtools package).
%    \begin{macrocode}
\applyCSVfile{translations.csv}{%
  \immediate\write\frenchdict{%
    \unexpanded{\deftranslation}{\insertLabel}{\insertFrenchValue}%
  }%
  \immediate\write\englishdict{%
    \unexpanded{\deftranslation}{\insertLabel}{\insertEnglishValue}%
  }%
}
%    \end{macrocode}
%
%    \begin{macrocode}
%</package>
%    \end{macrocode}
%
% \Finale
```